# Creating a multi-line string in javascript that accepts ruby object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

So I am trying to get my code to match Stripe's js example:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_REST_OF_MY_KEY');
```

Here are the lines from my `.js.erb` file that call the right key from my secrets.yml file. When this renders I get the following error in the browser console `Uncaught ReferenceError: pk_test_REST_OF_MY_KEY is not defined`

```
  var stripe = Stripe(
    <% if Rails.env == 'production' %>
      <%= Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key']).second[1].to_s %>
    <% else %>
      <%= Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key']).first[1].to_s %>
    <% end %>
  );
```

I've tried

```
... Stripe(` 
  RUBY LINES BETWEEN BACKTICKS 
`);

... Stripe(' + 
  RUBY LINES BETWEEN PLUSES 
+ ');
```

So it has to be some finicky js syntax with the `(' ');` not accepting the ruby value as a string, right? We know the ruby is running because the console error is printing the right value.

Also, the ruby is correct because it produces `Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key']).first[1].to_s
=> "pk_test_REST_OF_MY_KEY"` in the console

Comment: What's the actual JS that gets generated as a result?

Comment: You know @SergioTulentsev I'm new to working with js/front end. Would I look under Inspect > Elements or Page Source for that?

Comment: Yes, page source, for example.

Comment: You'll want to use View Source or inspect the server response in your dev tools' Network pane. The parsed DOM in the Elements pane will not reflect the actual source returned by the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think i should just be:

```
var stripe = Stripe(
  <% if Rails.env == 'production' %>
    '<%= Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key']).second[1].to_s %>'
  <% else %>
    '<%= Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key']).first[1].to_s %>'
  <% end %>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. That produces this error `only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed` from the view, which prevents the view from loading. It also results in some crazy syntax highlighting: http://imgur.com/xyGUzxs

Comment: Hmm now it looks like it is trying to run the right line, but `'<%= j(Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key']).first[1].to_s) %>'` but still outputting this error `only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed`

Comment: Alright, if I drop the `j()` and keep the ticks on each `<%= %>` line it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it will be helpful to clean up your code a bit to see what's happening where. Move the logic up to the top of the file:

```erb
<%
  config = Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key'])
  stripe_key = Rails.env.production? ? config.first[1] : config.second[1]
%>
```

...or, better, yet, a helper:

```ruby
def stripe_key
  config = Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key'])
  Rails.env.production? ? config.first[1] : config.second[1]
end
```

Then, in your JavaScript:

```erb
var stripe = Stripe('<%= j(stripe_key) %>');

// ...or...

var stripe = Stripe(<%= stripe_key.to_json %>);
```

Be careful to note the presence or absence of single-quotes in both cases. The [`j` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) will escape special characters (including quotes and newlines) inside the string, but the returned string won't be wrapped in quotation marks, whereas `to_json` will return a string already wrapped with double-quotes.

P.S. When you say this:

```ruby
Rails.application.secrets.stripe(['publishable_key'])
```

...are you sure you don't mean:

```ruby
Rails.application.secrets.stripe['publishable_key']

# ...or...

Rails.application.secrets.stripe.publishable_key
```